# Problem with in-app purchases in apple watch Swift

Tags: swift, watchkit, storekit, watchos

I have been trying in vain for several days to make a test purchase of a subscription from the watch, but nothing works out for me, all the methods that I found have been tried, and these are: apphud, rebooting devices, logging out with Apple ID, another Apple ID, test / not test apple id, sandbox is logged in, the appstore is also logged in, the card is linked, but, unfortunately, every time I try to buy, I get an error message: "***Unable to Purchase App**. Sign in with your Apple ID from the Apple Watch app on your iPhone*".

[image]

Moreover, when I do all the same from the phone, everything works fine, and the purchase is made.
There is an option to try **revenuecat**, but honestly, I don't think it will be different from apphud. There is also an assumption that it is simply IMPOSSIBLE to make a test purchase from the watch.
Here is a piece of my code from in app manager (recipes are coming):

```
func startProducts() {
    let bundle = appBundleID
    
    let products = Set([
        bundle + ".1m",
        bundle + ".1y"
    ])
    
    request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(products))
    
    request?.delegate = self
    request?.start()
}

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    guard firstRequestFinish else {
        return
    }
    firstRequestFinish = false
    defer {
        finishProducts()
    }
    if response.invalidProductIdentifiers.count > 0 {
        print("Invalid Products IDs: \(response.invalidProductIdentifiers)")
    }
    self.allProducts = response.products
    let subscriptions = (response.products.compactMap { item in
        return IAProduct(id: item.productIdentifier,
                         title: item.localizedTitle,
                         price: item.price,
                         localePrice: item.localizedPrice,
                         locale: item.priceLocale)
    }.sorted { item1, item2 in
        return item1.price.doubleValue < item2.price.doubleValue
    })
    self.availableSubscriptions = subscriptions
    if subscriptions.count > 0 {
        print("Available products IDs: \(subscriptions.map({ item in return item.id }))")
    }
    self.monthProduct = subscriptions.first { item in
        return item.id.contains(".1m")
    }
    self.yearProduct = subscriptions.first { item in
        return item.id.contains(".1y")
    }
    
    delegate?.inappWasLoaded()
}
```

I would be glad for any advice! Many thanks to everyone who will take part in the discussion of this issue.

Comment: Same bug here. I'm using swiftui + revenuecat. Have u tried something like this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649957?answerId=652522022#652522022